# sql - three table join

Tags: sql

Table Structure (which is not efficient, but I have to work with it, and I can't change it.):

University Table - UniversityName, UniversityId

BookLease Table - BookId, UniversityId, LeaseDate

Book Table - BookId, UniversityId, Category, Page_Count.

I've to find total pages read/leased so far for university that's name is "XYZ". This is what I have so far:

```
select sum(bookTable.Page_count) 
from University u
join (select bl.UniversityId AS universityId, b.page_count as Counter
       BookLease bl
       join Book bk
            on bl.BookId = bk.BookId) as bookTable
on  
     bookTable.universityId = u.UniversityId
where
     u.Name = "XYZ"
```

This seems wrong and inefficient. Is it? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Which SQL ? provide version too.

Comment: There's an error in your sql. b isn't a valid table alias. is page_count in Book or BookLease?

Comment: @Codeguy007: "Book Table - BookId, UniversityId, Category, Page_Count."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select 
   sum(b.page_count) as pages_read
   , count(bl.bookid) as no_leased
from university u 
   inner join book b on b.universityid = u.universityid
   inner join booklease bl on bl.bookid = b.bookid
                           and bl.universityid = u.universityid
where u.name = 'XYZ'
and bl.lease_date > [some lease date]
```

Comment: for total leased: select count(*) from booklease bl inner join university u on bl.universityid = u.universityid where u.universityName = 'xyz'

Comment: -1 If you don't join the `Book` table on the `BookLease` table then you only get the number of pages in the available books, not the number of pages read/leased.

Comment: @Guffa: I've added that to the join in the second SQL. Actualy, having re-read the question I've removed the first SQL.

Comment: Why are you counting bl.bookId? what does that represent? My query would have only one row - the total pages leased... how many rows will your query have? Also, is my query wrong or just inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Just join on the table directly, not on a subquery:

```
select
  sum(bk.Page_count) 
from
  University u
  inner join BookLease bl on bl.UniversityId = u.UniversityId
  inner join Book bk on bk.BookId = bl.BookId
where
  u.Name = "XYZ"
```